# Div slide out from side on Click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div come from the left/right side of the screen, and I tried using checkbox and label method however it does not work ( or I'm just doing something wrong) maybe someone know what to do? here's my project: 
 http://codepen.io/benasl/pen/vXWBxv/?editors=1100

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="sidebarToggler"> 

<input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="sidebarToggler2"> 

<div class="products">
   <label for="sidebarToggler" class="next right"><b>&#x276F</b></label>
   <label for="sidebarToggler2" class="next left"><b>&#x276E</b></label>  
<div id="wrap-products">
```

I need this effect for #wrap-products

Comment: can you add an scribble how it should look?

Comment: The #wrap-products (the div with 6 div ands arrows on the sides) should slide out from the middle to the side and the next div (#wrap-products2)  should slide in to it's place. I updated the link a bit. http://codepen.io/benasl/pen/vXWBxv/?editors=1100

Comment: you want the items pull from left sidebar >??

Comment: i want the #wrap-products to slide-out to the left from the screen and #wrap-products2 to the middle from right off the screen.

Comment: hey if I give to one sidebar from left without much styling will it be okay to you for the next one ??

Comment: sure sure that'd be fine

Comment: hey Did It worked or not ??

Answer (score 0):

hello see the below fiddle i just do it for one side bar obviously the other one will be same do your style according to your wish .check in the middle for sidenav.Add style with check box or label as your wish I just did the basic.

the basic javascript code is

```
   <script>
  function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
  </script>
```

here is the fiddle Demo .Hope It Helps.

[Sidebar Nav Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/DTcHh/25911/)

Answer (score 0):

I did modification to your code to resolve the issue you have.
See below code OR fiddle created.

CSS

```
body {
  height: 2000px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #707070;

}

.arrow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  opacity:0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 50px; 
  font-size: 40px;
  color:white;
  position:fixed;
  right: 20px; 
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
  padding: 2px;


}

#wrap {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.landing {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background: url("http://onehdwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Bee-Wallpapers-Desktop-HD-Pictures-3.jpg");
    background-repeat: none;
    position: top center;
    background-size: auto 1200px;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}


.about {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.icon {
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 400px;

}

h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.border {
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.products {
  width: 100%;
  /*overflow: hidden;
  height: 1500px; */
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

#wrap-products h2 {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

*.* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }

#products-wrap-main {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       overflow: hidden;
       width: 50%;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }

#wrap-products-container {
    width: 200%;   /*here is a tricky part */ 
}

#wrap-products {
  width: 50%; 
  display: block; 
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;

}
#wrap-products2 {
  display: block; 
  float: left;
  width: 50%; 
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;

}
/***********Mygtukai i sonus***************/

#Toggler {
  display: none;
}
#Toggler2 {
  display: none;
}
#Toggler:checked + .products #wrap-products {
  left: 1300px;
}
#Toggler2:checked + .products #wrap-products2 {
  left: 1000px;
}




@media screen and (min-width : 1024px) and (max-width : 1224px) {
  #wrap-products {
    /* width: 70%; */
    position: relative;
  }
}


@media screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {

  #wrap-products {
    /*width: 70%; */
    position: relative;
}

  #flex-products {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position:relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {

    #products-wrap-main {
        width: 620px; /* to limit the item 2 per row */
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 768px) {

    #products-wrap-main {
       width: 100%;
    }

    #flex-products {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position:relative;

  }
    #wrap-products,
    #wrap-products2{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #wrap-products-container {
    width: 100%;
    }
   #wrap-products #flex-products .icon-cube,
   #wrap-products2 #flex-products2 .icon-cube
             {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    height: 380px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}
  .products .next{
    display:none;
  }
}

#flex-products2 {
  width:100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


#flex-products {
  width:100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.products {
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
 /* padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px; */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.03);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
 /* height: 50px; */
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -20px;
    z-index: 20000000;

}
.right {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  /*height: 50px; */
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -20px;
  z-index: 20000000;
}
.next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 20000000;
}


.icon-cube {
  position: relative;
  height: 320px;
  width: 270px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.inside {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.footer {
  background:url("http://onehdwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Bee-Wallpapers-Desktop-HD-Pictures-3.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 10px -3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
.name {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#wrap-contacts {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;

}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#form {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  top: 220px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

#input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
}
.message {
    height: 230px;
    resize: none;

}
#input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    font-family: "century gothic";
}
#submit {
    background: white;
    border: none;
    font-family: "century gothic";
    color: black;
    width: 80px;
    padding:5px 0 5px 0;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  top: 220px;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
h3 {
  margin:0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.envelope {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 21px;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
.envelope:after {
 display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 12px;
  width: 50px;
}
.envelope:before {
 display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 12px;
  width: 50px;
}

.end {
  padding:30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color:#c9c9c9;
}
```

HTML

```
 <header class="landing">
</header>

<div class="about"> 
  <div class="arrow">&#x276E</div>
    <div id="wrap"> 
    <h1> About us </h1>
    <p class="border"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas in orci et sem mollis pulvinar in tristique ipsum. Nam ut mi ullamcorper, ultrices sapien eu, vulputate leo. Etiam non libero in urna aliquam suscipit eget id orci. Morbi egestas pulvinar ante quis imperdiet. Suspendisse fringilla vulputate justo, nec ultricies nunc tempus a.</p>
    <div class = "flex-wrap">    
      <div class="icon">Example</div>
      <div class="icon">Example</div>
      <div class="icon">Example</div>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>

<!--
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="Toggler2"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="Toggler">
--> 

<div class="products">

<div id="products-wrap-main">

    <div class="next right"><b>&#x276F</b></div>
    <div class="next left"><b>&#x276E</b></div>


    <div id="wrap-products-container">

    <div id="wrap-products">
      <h1> Products </h2>
      <h2> Example </h2>
      <div id="flex-products">    
        <div class="icon-cube">
        <div class="inside"></div> 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>

        <div class="icon-cube">
        <div class="inside"></div> 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>

        <div class="icon-cube ">
        <div class="inside"></div>  
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>

        <div class="icon-cube"> 
        <div class="inside"></div> 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>

        <div class="icon-cube">
        <div class="inside"></div>  
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>

        <div class="icon-cube">
        <div class="inside"></div> 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>



      </div> 
    </div>

    <div id="wrap-products2">
      <h1> Products </h1>
      <h2> Example </h2>
      <div id="flex-products2">    
        <div class="icon-cube">
        <div class="inside"></div> 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>

        <div class="icon-cube">
        <div class="inside"></div> 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>

        <div class="icon-cube ">
        <div class="inside"></div>  
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>

        <div class="icon-cube"> 
        <div class="inside"></div> 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
        <div class="icon-cube">
        <div class="inside"></div>  
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
        <div class="icon-cube">
        <div class="inside"></div> 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>



      </div> 
    </div> 
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

</div>


  <div class="footer">

    <div class="filter"></div>

    <div id="wrap-contacts">

      <div class="name"><h1>Contact us</h1><span class="envelope">&#x2709</span></div>

         <form id="form" action="contact.php" method="post">
           <input id="input" class="subject" type="text" name="cf_name" placeholder="Subject"><br>
           <input id="input" class="mail" type="text" name="cf_email" placeholder="Email"><br> 
           <textarea id="input" class="message" type="text" name="cf_message" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br> 
                  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">    
                  </form>    
      <div class="text"><h3>Example</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas in orci et sem mollis pulvinar in tristique ipsum. Nam ut mi ullamcorper, ultrices sapien eu, vulputate leo.</div>     
    </div> 

</div>

<div class="end">@ Company's name</div>
```

JS( Kindly include after jQuery)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                $('.arrow').css('opacity', '0');
            }
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
                $('.arrow').css('opacity', '.5');
            }
        });

        $(".next.right").click(function () {
            $("#wrap-products-container").animate({
                marginLeft:"-100%"
            },300);
        });

         $(".next.left").click(function () {
            $("#wrap-products-container").animate({
                marginLeft:"0%"
            },300);
        });
    });
```

Also,  please see the fiddle (resize the fiddle window for desktop view with arrow in action ) -

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/4466bpx2/
```

Hope this will help you.